# Al generar el reporte, se muestra la fecha con 4 horas de diferencia

Tags: php, sql, timestamp, timezone

Registro eventos con hora de inicio 8:00am, pero al generar un reporte este me modifica la hora agregando 4 horas y se visualiza como 12:00hrs. Me da la idea que es la zona horaria, ya que todos los resultados en su hora de inicio y término tienen 4 horas más.

Cuando voy a editar los eventos, estos siempre tienen la hora correcta ingresada.

¿Cómo podría corregir este error que me imagino solo es de visualización?

Mi consulta sql que hace referencia a los registros de hoy:

```
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time ,'%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

Mi código donde se despliega la información:

```
$unix_timestamp = $mostrar['start_time'];
$inicio = new DateTime("@$unix_timestamp");

$unix_timestamp = $mostrar['end_time'];
$termino = new DateTime("@$unix_timestamp");
?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['nombre'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['evento'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['moderador'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $inicio->format('H:i');?></td>
    <td><?php echo $termino->format('H:i');?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['saladeconferencia'] ?></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Cuando creas el datetime puedes ponerle el timezone como segundo parámetro. Añádelo para que te ponga la fecha correcta

Comment: @Jakala sin resultado amigo :(

Comment: hola puede decirnos que te sale cuando imprimes esto:  `echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';` y en que zona horaria crees que debería estar funcionando tu web?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema esta en el archivo de configuracion de php, **php.ini** , debes editar el archivo y setear su configuracion horaria a la cual deseas.

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone =
```